# Fastest way to generate a bytes array of words combinations gives by stdin in python

Tags: python, performance, passwords, combinations

I want to generate a byte array  of combinations/permuations (uppercase, lowercase...) of each word given by stdin at my python script as faster  as possible.
this bytes array will be send reccursively as a batch to a cuda kernel for parralelel treatment.

this is a python code example of what i want to do:

I want to avoid c programming to fast modify the generation of candidates with the easy string maniuplation in python

```
import time
import os

from tqdm import tqdm
import string

import re
import sys
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool 

import io
    

def combs_word(w):

    list_candidates=bytearray()
    n_cands=0   
    for n in range(1,100):

        for k in range(3):
            if k==0:
                w2=w.upper()
            if k==1:
                w2=w.lower()
            if k==2:
                w2==w.title()
            
            cand=w2*n
            list_candidates+=cand.encode()
            n_cands+=1
    return list_candidates,n_cands


for line in sys.stdin:
    lw=[]

    w=line.rstrip()
    
    start=time.time()
    l_candidates,n_cands=combs_word(w)
    
    #... do CUDA STUFF with l_candidates..

    end=time.time()
    speed=n_cands/(end-start)
    print('speed %.3f combinations/Sec:'%speed)
```

This is the fastest code i've found (threading benchmark of combs_words is not better)

This code is executed as below:

```
$cat wordlist | python3 combinations.py
```

On my computer this speed is "only" about 2M combinations /sec but it is a bottleneck for my cuda kernel capable of treating around 50M/sec of combinations.

Regards
Fanch

Comment: I have a hard time to grasp what you are actually doing. Why that for-loop from 1 to 100 of repeated input line contents? Can you write down that problem with a bit more formality pls?

Comment: this line `for n in range(1,100)` makes no sense at all. You are using `n` in line `cand=w2*n` but then you are not using `cand` at all

Comment: Yes you've right I made a mistake. I fixed by replacing w by cand.

Comment: the main goal of this code is only to benchmark the speed of string generation with python. In my work i want to fill a byte buffer with different candidate  derived from a list of word as faster as possible. The buffer would be for eg foo|FOO|Foo|foofoo|FOOFOO|FooFoo| ...

Comment: When the byte buffer is full (a memory allocation of 100Mb = around 15M word combinations) the buffer is send to the GPU where multiple thread are executed through a cuda kernel. The Cuda execution is very fast (around 50M combinations/sec) but the string generation is relatively slow (2M combinations/sec)

Comment: tested your code again and again it makes no sense, for `foo foo2` it does produce multiple unnecessary copies of the same combination `FOO FOO2foo foo2foo foo2FOO FOO2FOO FOO2foo foo2foo foo2foo foo2foo foo2FOO FOO2FOO FOO2FOO FOO2foo foo2foo foo2foo foo2foo foo2foo foo2foo...`

Comment: I know that there will be duplicate in the list result. Sorry for my bad explanation of it.Consider this code only like a benchmark to measure the "average" speed that a python loop can fill a bytes array. the <code>for n in range(1,100)</code> is only executed to simulate a more complex string manipulation/permutation etc.. .